# SSH tunneling with relay and dynamic IPs

Tags: networking, server, ssh, proxy, vnc

I am trying to achieve a vnc connection through ssh tunnel from a computer on a private network, and to another one on another private network, using a public server as relay.
It can be graphically described with following schema:

```
|--------------|    |----------|    |--------------|
|locale machine|    |  server  |    |remote machine|
| ip:  x.x.x.x |===>|ip:1.2.3.4|===>| ip:  x.x.x.x |
|         out:A|    |in:B out:C|    |in:D          |
|--------------|    |----------|    |--------------|
```

Let me explain it:

- The locale machine is the one on which I want to run my VNC client. It is on a private network, so it can't be accessed directly.
- Through port A (I don't really care this one), it have to create a SSH tunnel to port B of server
- Server redirects incoming message from port B to port C (Not important too)
- Port C was tunneled by remote machine to redirect message to itself, targeting the VNC server. This machine is also on a private network, so I can't target it directly by IP from my local machine nor my server

The difficulty is that neither origin nor destination IP is known. The only one is the server, that I can configure the way I want. We'll asume that I can't edit anything in my private networks firewalls configurations

I read many tutos and articles on SSH tunnels or VNC with proxy, but I can't understand if it fulfill my needs. So, the question I really want to ask is not "How to do it?" but "Why and how does your solution work?".

Also, if possible, I'd like to achieve it with the simplest tools, to check, for example, my computer status from my Android, everywhere.

Thank you for your attention, and, in advance, for your help & explanations.

---

Edit: in case this help:

- local machine: OSx 10.10.5
- server: Ubuntu 15.04 server with non-standard ssh port
- remote machine: Ubuntu 16.04 / Fedora 23

Comment: do you have access to the routers/firewalls of the machines on the private networks?

Comment: No. I'd like to do this from the network of friends, for example... So I won't reconfigure their routers everytime.

Comment: There in is the problem, you have to think of the router/firewall as a fence between the real world IP address of your friends, and the fake ones their machines are given on the inside of the fence.  Each router would need to know what address inside the fence should be receiving the traffic.  so when your server requests from their network a connection, their router/firewall knows where to send it.

Comment: Are you only trying to control and monitor your own systems, but maybe while visiting your friends?  By that I mean you are on their network, but you want to look at your systems.  Not be on your network and control/view theirs.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I often let my computers run at my office, doing long operation, and I'd like to see if they ended to pick them up.

I controle both source & destination systems, and a server. I thought that I could make ssh tunnels from my source to server & my destination to server, then use them to drive a vnc protocole

Comment: If possible, I'd like to avoid any firewall/router config, and use proxy/tunnels instead, or things like that

Comment: And you have control of your own Router/firewall?

Comment: Well, in most cases, no. Isn't it possible without specific firewall config?

Comment: I don't want to put an answer in yet, but you can't avoid the Firewall/router.  They are a fence keeping the real world out, but you want to open a secure hole in them, so you can access your machines.  That is totally possible and the good news is you don't need the server in between, you just need to open your router, and only yours so you can tunnel in.

Comment: So, using tunnels to a known and opened relay is not possible? I wanted to use the intermediate server to avoid opening anything in firewalls. Because if the ssh tunnel is created from both sides to server, firewall will let them go. I do it quite often. It's just the redirection from the AB tunnel to CD that I can't solve, and make the whole thing work...

Comment: How do you connect from outside your network set up an SSH tunnel to inside your network, without touching the firewall or router?  Something must have been configured to allow translation from the outside world to inside IP address?think about your boxes   local machine internal IP address of 192.168.1.2, router IP 0f 69.23.45.6, how does your SSH tunnel reach 192.168.1.2, without hitting 63.23.45.6, and being translated to the other?

Comment: Ok, let me re-rexplain what I was thinking about

A makes an SSH tunnel to B.
D makes an SSH tunnel to C.
(I think that there's no problem until that, as each firewall will see an outgoing connection to the server).
Then the server connects on his own ports B & C.

Next, VNC should normally be able to send to D via A, and it will do AB with first outgoing SSH tunnel, BC (?) & CD, reversing 2nd SSH outgoing tunnel
This way, I have no ingoing connections, just outgoing that drives ingoing packets

Comment: OK, I understand better what you are wanting to do.   I think the answer is a VPN.  but I usually those go from point a directly to point b, I do not know of one that works in the manner you are talking about a middle man on the internet that allows 2way traffic between 2 tunnels coming to it.

Comment: I think you mean A makes a tunnel to B, C makes a tunnel to B, and then  AC can now talk to each other.

Comment: Yes, that's it, but because I was talking about ports on each machine, B & C are both on my server, but are different ports. I looked at VPN, it seems to be exactly what I need. Moreover, VPN architecture needs a server to be, if I understood correctly, the virtual router of the virtual network. In your 2-computers VPN, maybe you hosted the server on your source/destination system. But for me, I'll have to install it on my public server. I'll continue to pick up some informations about it, it seems to be interesting.

Comment: Yes, you need a VPN device/server that is on the public IP network, once the two machines tunnel into the VPN device, they can now see each other because they are on the same Virtual Private network.  I am going to write this up as the answer, does that sound good to you?

Comment: Yep, really good. I'll just then have to set up this on each of my devices, and I'll be thankful forever haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the scenario Alexandre needs a VPN device/server that is on the public internet.

> locale machine makes tunnel <==> VPN Server <==> remote machine makes tunne|

Once both machines are tunneled into the VPN device, they can see each other, and he can do the work he wants.

Another answer is for Alexandre is to open up Tunneling using his firewall/router, and just VPN directly to his network via the Real IP address for his firewall/router.  This would cut out the middle man and could serve the same purpose.

Machine makes tunnel <==> Router/Firewall this then gives him access to his server.

Comment: Let's try it. I will use [this french doc](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/openvpn), and will keep you in touch. Thanks for your help

Comment: Even if I had not yet the time to end the whole config, I mark your response as the accepted one. Thank you again.

Comment: Merci, et bonne chance à mon ami .

Comment: Yes, I did it, it works like a charm, even on osX. Ping is quite high between my 2 clients as they are each 600ms ping with the server, so the average between them is 1200ms, and activating "Client-to-client" directive on server does not allow them to dial directly. But nevermind, it does the job :D it's so fun, it makes my day! Thank you sooooooooooooo much! :D

Comment: You are very welcome, and just FYI, VPN is usually a bit slower due to the encryption.